# Isolation forest, how to use multiple features to predict, getting all anomalies

Tags: scikit-learn, isolation

I am trying to build an isolation forest using scikit learn and python to detect anomalies. I have attached an image of what the data may look like, and I am trying to predict 'pages' based on several 'size' features. [image]
When I print(anomaly), every single row is detected as -1, an anomaly. Is this because I am only using 'size2' to classify them? Is there a way to use multiple columns to help in detecting the anomalies? Should I be making n_features equal to the number of columns I am using? Thank you so much for your help.

```
model = IsolationForest(n_estimators = 100, max_samples = 'auto', contamination = 'auto')
model.fit(df[['pages']])
df['size2'] = model.decision_function(df[['pages']])
df['anomaly']= model.predict(df[['pages']])
print(df.head(50))
anomaly = df.loc[df['anomaly']==-1]
anomaly_index = list(anomaly.index)
print(anomaly)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure an isolation forest is appropriate here. If you want to predict `pages` column values based on size data, you would be better off using either a regression model or a classifier (I can't tell whether `pages` is categorical based on the data shown). With that said, if you do want to do anomaly detection, you have to make sure that you're fitting your model on the same subset of features you use for prediction. To detect anomalies based on the size features looks something like this:

```py
df['anomaly'] = model.fit_predict(df[['size2', 'size3', 'size4']])
```

Any subset of columns can be chosen to train the model on, but calls to both `fit` and `predict` must be made with the same feature set.

In the code given, the model is trained on the `label` column but used to predict outliers based on the `pages` column. Although the `label` column isn't shown, if the values in it are substantially different than those in the `pages` column it's not surprising that they would all be categorized as outliers. In addition, as written the `size2` column is not being used as a feature for prediction but rather being overwritten by the decision function scores for the `pages` column.

Comment: Thank you so much! The 'label' should actually be 'pages', sorry for the confusion!

Comment: When I added df['anomaly'] = df.fit_predict(df[['size2', 'size3', 'size4']]), I got the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'fit_predict', do you know why this is? Thanks!

Comment: Yes; sorry about that! Should have been `model.fit_predict`, it's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much!